# In Apache Arrow, what's the best practice to concat 2 ValueVector?

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I have 2 **Arrow ValueVectors** with same type, what's the best practice of concat 2 valuevectors? One way I know is calling ValueVector.copyFrom(fromInde, thisIndex, source), is there any better way of doing it?

vector1: {1, 2, 3} vector2: {4, 5, 6}

expected result after concat: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

**Pay attention please, this is Apache Arrow ValueVector, not normal JAVA collection.**

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Arrow Java API, but I think you have to build a new `ValueVector` and copy the elements from the vectors to be concatenated by yourself (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/vector.html#vector-life-cycle). Only the Python API seems to provide a `concat_arrays` method, which presumably allocates a new array with new data buffer(s) and copies the content of its arguments into it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes, this is the way I do right now, loop through source vector and call copyFrom one by one, it doesn't look like a good solution. I think this is a common requirement, I don't know why I didn't find any API related to it.